# I am unable to run my test cases in contanerized enviroment - "session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74"

Tags: google-chrome, docker, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am trying to run my test cases in docker previously it was running fine but now it showing error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW3f5.png)

I tried to downgrade the version but unable to do so

This is my Docker file

[Docker file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grsGM.png)

For the same docker file it was running previously

Is there any way to downgrade the chrome version and chrome driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***There are 2 reasons when this issue may occur.***

***1. Case when WebDriverManager is not in use and somehow chromedriver.exe binary was updated*** which supports chrome browser version 74 but OS having browser as 72. In this case you would need to update binary compatible to browser version.

***2. When WebDriverManager is in use which downloads browser binary automatically.*** Its tries to download latest chromedriver binary which may not be compatible to your chrome browser installed version let say 72 (my guess). If so, in that case we have to tell WebDriverManager to download chromedriver binary which would be compatible to your browser version 72. For doing so, please take a reference of below line and do update your code.

***WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("2.46").setup();***

Note - We have added version("2.46") that means WebDriverManager would find out this specific version of chromedriver binary.

Let's know if this resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help , it is resolved now . I have done few changes in my docker file and pulled the image of chromium and protractor from Dockerhub and downgraded the chrome driver to 2.46 . it is working fine now

Comment: Please accept the answer and vote up. So others know looking at answer was useful.